# dispatch_async block loses the varible values

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

I have an Objective-C++ function like this:

```
-(void)foo:(const List&)vectorList
{
    dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
        [koo:vectorList];
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes that in koo function, the vectorList is losing the data, say the vector becomes empty. It doesn't always happen. I do not why. Any one has idea about it?

Comment: Probably race condition where you do something with vectorList somewhere else

Comment: You should create objects on heap and use `shared_ptr` for dispatching.

Answer (score 3):

> the vectorList is losing the data

Your block is capturing a *reference*, not a copy of whatever is referenced. If after creating the block but before it is executed whatever is referenced is mutated then the block will see those mutations.

If you want the block to operate on the referenced value at the point the block is created you will have to make a copy of it and capture that copy.

HTH